# Illogical "undefined offset"!

Tags: php

this is my debug code:

```
        echo $val2[ $key ];
        echo $val2[ 0 ];
        echo $val2[ "0" ];
        var_dump( $val2 );
        die();
```

this is the output:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in index.php on line 319

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in index.php on line 320

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in index.php on line 321
array(1) { ["0"]=> float(0.123)  }
```

this is making me crazy, why does it say there is no key when there clearly is?

Comment: I think this is the correct one `echo $val2[ 0 ];` maybe remove the spaces? `echo $val2[0];` you could also use print_r instead of var_dump (the output is less verbose)

Comment: thanks for your replies, i realise the problem came from json_decode, I added (array) infront, instead of adding true as argument 2 to make it return as an array

Comment: @JayBlanchard `var_dump` always shows array keys in brackets, they're not really part of the key. Look at `var_dump(array("0" => "foo"));`

Comment: Dang - missed the var dump @Barmar. I shouldn't be looking at Stack on pain killers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came from

```
$val2 = (array) json_decode( $data );
```

should be:

```
$val2 = json_decode( $data, true );
```